# grep exact word match (-w) does not work with file paths in a text file

Tags: linux, shell, grep

Im trying to grep for a filename with fullpath in a file which contains something like 'ls -l' output, but it fails to match it correctly.

Line in the shell script which does the string search

```
pcline=`grep -w "$file1" $file2` # grep for file1 in file2 contents
```

if i echo the command, the output of command looks like below

```
grep -w run /home/rajesh/rootfs.layout

Expected
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Aug 28 run

Actual
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Aug 28 bin/run-parts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Aug 28 run
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 303 Aug 28 tests/aes/run.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 445 Aug 28 tests/auto_ui/run.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 320 Aug 28 tests/available_memory/run.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 308 Aug 28 tests/fonts/run.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 309 Aug 28 tests/html_config_page/run.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 361 Aug 28 tests/ipc/run.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 304 Aug 28 tests/JSON/run.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 303 Aug 28 tests/log4cplus_cpp/run.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 301 Aug 28 tests/log4cplus_c/run.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 751 Aug 28 tests/msm_basic/run.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 472 Aug 28 tests/res_man_dependency/run.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 465 Aug 28 tests/res_man_ipc/run.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 789 Aug 28 tests/res_man_multi_process/run.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 469 Aug 28 tests/res_man_private_client/run.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 492 Aug 28 tests/res_man_public_client/run.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 311 Aug 28 tests/virt_mem_config/run.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 Aug 28 var/run]
```

The trick i tried is to add a white space, which is guaranteed in my input file, this works in console, but not when it is assigned to a variable.

```
grep " tests/aes/run.sh" /home/rajesh/rootfs.layout
```

Line in the script

```
pcline=`grep \"" $file1"\" $file2`     # grep for file1 in file2 contents
```

Please let me know if i have committed any errors in this script.

Comment: Why is that an unexpected result? A word is delimited by a non-alphanumeric character. So `grep -w run ...` will match a line with `foo.run.bar`, for example. Did you try `pcline=\`grep " $file1" $file2\`` without the escaped quotes?

Comment: @mbratch, sorry it did not work with => pcline=`grep " $filename" $pc_layout`

Comment: Interesting. I'm supposing that there's something else in your scenario not visible in your posting. It worked for me when I ran a test case, but looks like you received a solution already. Cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `egrep` like this:

```
egrep "(^| )$file1( |$)" "$file2"
```

If `file1="run"` then above command will match string `run` preceded by line start or space and followed by space or line end.

Comment: it worked well with all the files except two, but they look like weird files to me. 1) lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Aug 28 usr/bin/[
2) lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Aug 28 usr/bin/[[

Comment: result was something like this egrep: Unmatched [ or [^

Comment: Yes because `[` is actually a filename in `/usr/bin` I will see how I can provide you a workaround in few minutes.

Comment: Well the easy fix would be to escape the `[` when you  set your value in file1 like this: `file1='\['`

Comment: i have modified my script to handle the exception for those two files and it does work, thanks